# Memory leak while destroying a BST

Tags: c++, memory, memory-leaks, binary-search-tree

I'm trying to code a destructor for my BST so that I don't have to delete everything manually.
I've tried multiple destructors for my BST but I keep getting a memory leak when running with valgrind.
Here is my code (destructor at the end of code).

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
//struct for names
struct User
{
    string firstname;
    string lastname;
};


//BST struct where the data in the BST are the names in struct User
struct BST
{
    User* value;
    int key=0;
    BST* leftTree;
    BST* rightTree;
};
// creates a BST ( I do it like this incase i want to run a new function on a BST, but with a field to keep track of the size and initialize to 0)
BST* createBST(){
    BST* n = nullptr;
    return n;
}
// checks if empty
bool isEmpty(BST* tree){
    if(tree == nullptr){
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
// destroy the BST completely.
void destroy(BST* tree){
    if (tree != nullptr){
        delete tree->value;
        destroy(tree->leftTree);
        destroy(tree->rightTree);
        delete tree;
    }
}
```

Main to see if code works:

```
// TEST to see if code works correctly.
int main() {
    BST* bst = createBST();
    // I don't have an insert function yet so I do it manually
    bst = new BST;
    bst->key = 15;
    bst->value = new User{"John","15"};
    bst->leftTree = new BST;
    bst->leftTree->key = 5;
    bst->leftTree->value = new User{"John","15"};
    destroy(bst);
    return 0;
}
```

edit:
added delete tree->value;
but I still get this error:

```
==34== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==34== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==34== Using Valgrind-3.14.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==34== Command: student/labo12
==34==
==34== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==34==    at 0x400923: destroy(BST*) (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==    by 0x400950: destroy(BST*) (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==    by 0x400950: destroy(BST*) (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==    by 0x400ABD: main (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==
==34== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==34==    at 0x400923: destroy(BST*) (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==    by 0x400960: destroy(BST*) (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==    by 0x400950: destroy(BST*) (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==    by 0x400ABD: main (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==
==34== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==34==    at 0x400923: destroy(BST*) (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==    by 0x400960: destroy(BST*) (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==    by 0x400ABD: main (in /task/student/labo12)
==34==
==34==
==34== HEAP SUMMARY:
==34==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==34==   total heap usage: 8 allocs, 8 frees, 208 bytes allocated
==34==
==34== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==34==
==34== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==34== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==34== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Count the number of `new` operators and `delete` operators in your code. They should match. But it your code you care only of the `BST` objects, and never delete the `User`.

Why don't you implement the destructor of `BST` that correctly deletes all the fields?

**Update** Ok, after deleting the `User` you have a problem of incorrectly initialized fields. You have no explicit constructor for `BST`, so the pointers to left, right and user are initialized with junk. That is what valgrind points you to now.

Comment: I noticed I wasn't delete user. But even if I delete it I still get errors.
I don't know what you mean by correctly deletes all the fields.

Comment: @FieldyScop, see update. BTW, why do you call your function "destructors"? Why not to implement real destructors?

Comment: *Count the number of new operators and delete operators in your code.* dangerous assertion in the face of complex code. 1 `new` could have many paths to `delete`ion, but never travels more than one of them. Do your best to keep to 1:1 correlation, though. A sane programmer does their best to keep things simple.

Comment: @user4581301, this approach is good to start with. My main idea was that the fact that the `new` is used to create a *User* should be a hint.